# App not available under a non-admin user

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-powerpoint, administrator, microsoft-office-2016

I created a non-admin account on my Windows 10 laptop with Microsoft Office but   PowerPoint is not present. It's available and working fine under the admin account.  In the non-admin account, when I go to Windows 10 `Settings/Apps/Apps & features`, PowerPoint isn't even listed, so there is no "repair" button to click.  I clicked repair under my admin account, and it still isn't available in the non-admin account. How do I make it available for my non-admin user account?

Comment: So, other Office parts work but not Powerpoint?

Comment: Yes, everything else works under both admin and non-admin.

Comment: Could be something related with the license but that would affect all office, I think. No idea, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it anyway. If I figure it out, I'll document what it is here.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/multiple-users-one-computer-office-2013-not/6abaf5d4-3be4-4290-be47-9295e1cfa825 not sure if related but perhaps a start.

Comment: I actually saw that too, but it didn't help me. Nice try though!

Comment: Microsoft office doesn’t typically list individual apps in the add / remove programs list. Have you tried clicking the start button and typing PowerPoint in? I mean, how do you know it isn’t there? Maybe the icon is just missing.

Comment: It doesn't show up when I type there either. No icon, no app..